# how to use simulators to compute the energy consumption

Tags: ldpc

If I use a open source simulator (OAI 5GNR ULSIM/DLSIM) for realizing a wireless uplink transmission channel and transmits a LDPC coded data. My question is how to use it to compute the energy consumption (total power i.e. dynamic and static times execution time) on a device. I had implemented LDPC encoder c language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A software implementation of a decoder has no real relationship to the hardware implementation of the decoder in actual devices. The encoder is relatively simple, but would still be implemented differently for at least the LDPC codes in 5G (QC-LDPC with medium-sized circulants).

And: Even when just comparing software implementations, processors that execute (compiled) C code are *wildly* different! There's probably C programs running on your baking oven's clock display with an 8 bit CPU with 256 bytes of RAM, but there's also C running on 192-core servers with 1 TB of RAM. As you can imagine, these processors are efficient in different use cases.